# Is there a way to bypass my ISP's port blocking? Port forwarding, Ubuntu

Tags: server, 16.04, minecraft, port-forwarding

I recently have been building a Minecraft server for fun, and running it off of my computer. Now I want friends and other players to be able to join it.
Naturally, I port forwarded and turned off router IPv4 firewall. But, it turns out my ISP is blocking the ports I need (25565) to be forwarded to me! Am I screwed, or is there a way to safely bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way around this situation is to change the port that your server is on (somewhere in the server.properties), change it to something like 25566, or a port that isn't blocked.

Your friends will have to add the port to the end of it (like myserverdomain:25566), or you can make an alias (through a free service like noip) to use the port, so when you navigate to myaliasdomain, it will redirect you to myserverdomain:25566.

I've done this before, and it worked well, although the free alias options are limited to certain base domains, so you may need to pay money if you want something nice.

Note, ISP's don't usually block port 25565. Are you sure your router has been port-forwarded correctly?

EDIT: More Information:

The port is not locked to 25565, you can change it, and in this case, you'll have to. I can walk you through it if you need, we can chat about it, let me know.

The only places you have to change it is:

1. The server properties
2. The server machine firewall (if the server has a firewall)
3. The port forwarding
4. The clients

For the clients, you can either:

- Tell them your new address (123.456.789.123:25566)
- Create an alias to your external IP then tell your clients (mydomain.org:25566 where mydomain.org points to 123.456.789.123)
- Make an alias that redirects including the port (mydomain.org where mydomain.org points to 123.456.789.123:25566)

Personally, I decided to combine both the 2nd and 3rd option for changing IP. I make one alias to my ip, and another that points to my previous alias but with the port attached to the end. So I did mydomain.org = 123.456.789.123, then myminecraftserver.org = mydomain.org:25566. This way, when my external IP changes, I can just change mydomain.org, as well as the possibility of a webserver, ssh server, or other services using mydomain.org.

The problem I alluded to before is, using a direct IP in your minecraft clients is very unreliable. Your ISP *will* change your external IP every so often, and once that happens, all your clients will no longer see your server as online. When using a dynamic domain name service, you can update your domain (mydomain.org) to your changed IP whenever it changes, and just give all your clients the domain. That way, they just use mydomain.org or mydomain.org:25566, which is easier to type and remember, and your clients will stay connected when your external IP changes.

If you're looking for a free dynamic hosting service to get your own personal "mydomain.org", I would suggest the "NoIP" company. Search them on Google. They are free to use as long as you verify your domain is still being used every 30 days.

Comment: I suggest a port in the 8000 range, like 8084.

Comment: @AndroidDev The problem is it has to be port 25565(The minecraft port), thats the port I am listening to(I think, I am new to this, I just know there is no way I can change the port without it not working)

Comment: @WindowBreaker - You'll have to change the port that the client is listening on.

Comment: Im not sure I understand, do you mean the Minecraft game client?

Comment: @WindowBreaker - Probably, if that's what you're trying to connect to the server from. I don't play Minecraft, so I can't really help you there.

Comment: @AndroidDev That means I would have to change the port for every single client, I guess the best idea is to add a custom port at the end of my IP like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port like what Zzzach... said

Comment: @Zzzach... http://i.imgur.com/A9PGFuv.png

Comment: Also they are blocking about 95% of ports between 1 and 3000, luckily the ISP is a small local business so maybe I can persuade them to unblock the ports for me?

Comment: @WindowBreaker I don't think they will make an exception for one minecraft server host. :( I have updated my answer with more information, please check it above.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Choose different ports. I built ubuntu headless minecraft servers before. you can choose different ports in the configuration file and then have those ports mapped via port forwarding on your router. oh and never turn off your router firewall. you make every device on your network vulnerable.

Comment: I meant, I turned off my IPv4 firewall

Comment: @WindowBreaker Only turn off your firewall for testing, never keep it off for extended times.